# Few questions about a Function.prototype.bind() polyfill

Tags: javascript

I'm following along the YDKJS book series, and I came upon this snippet in "this & Object Prototypes".

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
        if (typeof this !== "function") {
            // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
            // internal IsCallable function
            throw new TypeError(
                "Function.prototype.bind - what is trying " +
                "to be bound is not callable"
            );
        }
        var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
            fToBind = this,
            fNOP = function(){},
            fBound = function(){
                return fToBind.apply(
                    (
                        this instanceof fNOP && 
                        oThis ? this : oThis 
                    ),
                    aArgs.concat(
                        Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments )
                    )
                );
            }
        ;
        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
        fBound.prototype = new fNOP(); 

        return fBound;
    };
}
```

So pretty much I want to understand what's going on in the fBound definition. I understand that it's a function wrapper that contains an apply that takes two arguments, i.e., the *this* context and the arguments array, but I don't understand how the *this* conditional works or why aArgs is concatenating itself to itself (wouldn't that just give a twice as long arguments object with duplicates for every element?) I'm also not totally confident I understand what setting the prototypes at the end achieves. I would appreciate some help demystifying this for academic purposes (I realize I'd never actually need to write this code).

Edit: I understand now

Comment: Before we cover this: there is almost never any reason to use `bind()` in modern JS. As for the explanation: JS uses, at its core, a prototype based object system, and any function is _also_ a constructor as long as you use `new`. By attaching a prototype to a function, you've done literally that: property lookups will now cascade up through that prototype. Lots of tutorials about this fairly essential JS concept on the web, e.g. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/prototype-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the comment/resource. I understand that I guess. What I don't understand is the specific interaction between fNOP and the function we're calling bind on. I also don't understand the specifics of what's going on to determine _this_ inside of fBound's definition or why aArgs is concatenating itself to itself.